redirect problem when file_get_html on php
I want to see html source of 'https://piugame.com' on php. but I got error code like this.

Warning: file_get_contents(https://piugame.com): Failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /simple_html_dom.php on line 82

So, I access 'https://piugame.com' on iframe tag. turn on the DevTools and saw this redirect loop.

What is this? and How can I stop this loop?
this is php code about to get html source
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html('https://piugame.com');
    echo $html;
?>

and this is html code about to see redirect loop
<HTML>
<iframe src="https://piugame.com"></iframe>
</HTML>


What does PHP have in common with the browser request?

piugame.com loads successfully in an iframe:


<iframe src="https://piugame.com"></iframe>



so it is not related to piugame.com. Yet, looking at your requests and seeing you have SSO, this surely looks like you have an IDP (Identity Provider), which is responsible to provide identity to your SP (Service Provider), so your SP sends a POST request to your IDP to authenticate, your IDP response in some manner (for example you are not authenticated at your IDP), which in turn sends a request, specifying your sid (maybe a JWT token), which in turn responds with you not being properly authenticated, so your IDP is requested again and the cycle continues.
This happens due to simple_html_dom.php where you want to ensure authentication. So you will need to carefully study how simple_html_dom.php works, why your authentication gets into an endless loop rather than providing an identity or responding with a failure and it would not hurt to study your requests too, including payload, HTTP status and response.
It's also possible that you have some server error, so you will also need to check your server logs.
